# .on("click",...) not working on objects created with the same on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

since I am new to JS / jQuery it is probably a obvious problem (but no exception thrown). I read that I can't use .onclick so i tried this approach with .on("click"...)

I try to build a table that adds new lines under the clicked line. This should also work for the newly created lines.

My html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="line1"><td>Stuff1</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td></tr>
    <tr id="line2"><td>Stuff2</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td></tr>
    <tr id="line3"><td>Stuff3</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td></tr>
    <tr id="line4"><td>Stuff4</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

My JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>    

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("tr").on("click",function(){
            var childId = $(this).attr("id")+1;
            if($("#"+childId).length){
                $("#"+childId).toggle();
            }else{
                $(this).after('<tr id="'+childId+'"><td>Stuffxxxx</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
                //AJAX
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Use event delegation.

Comment: `var childId = $(this).attr("id")+1;` This isn't going to magically turn `line1` into `line2`, it's going to make `line11`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>    

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("table").on("click","tr", function(){
            var childId = $(this).attr("id")+1;
            if($("#"+childId).length){
                $("#"+childId).toggle();
            }else{
                $(this).after('<tr id="'+childId+'"><td>Stuffxxxx</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
                //AJAX
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```